# How do I pass information from the user that submits a ModelForm to a ManyToMany save?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to insert a records into an intersection table from a Django ModelForm utilizing a CreateView but I'm not sure how to access information from the currently logged in user. I've tried request.user but I don't know where to put it in my view or form and each time I get the same error of "null value in column 'school_id' violates not-null constraint." All other values are correct. Can someone teach me the proper way to do this? I'd really appreciate it.

I tried to put this in my view but it didn't work:

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.applicant = self.request.user
        g = Group.objects.get(name='PendingApplicants')
        g.user_set.add(self.request.user)

        for program in form.cleaned_data['programs']:
            pro = tblProgramSchool()
            pro.application_id = self.object
            pro.program = program
            pro.school = self.request.user.mainschool
            pro.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I tried this in my form but it also didn't work:

```py
    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = forms.ModelForm.save(self, False)

        old_save_m2m = self.save_m2m

        def save_m2m():
            old_save_m2m
            instance.programs.clear()
            for program in self.cleaned_data['programs']:
                instance.programs.add(program = program, school = self.request.user.mainschool)



            self.save_m2m = save_m2m

            instance.save()
            self.save_m2m()

            return instance
```

I know I'm missing something fundamental but after reading through a bunch of answers and Django documentation I'm feeling lost.

models.py

```py
class Application(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    applicant = models.ForeignKey('users.CustomUser', null = False, blank = False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    programs = models.ManyToManyField(tblProgram, blank = True, through = tblProgramsSchool)


class tblProgramsSchool(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    school = models.ForeignKey(tblSchool, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    program = models.ForeignKey(tblProgram, on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    application = models.ForeignKey('Application', on_delete=models.PROTECT)


class tblProgram(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null = False, blank = False)

    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True, blank = True)


class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    """A model for a custom user"""
...

    mainschool = models.ForeignKey(tblSchool, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)

...
```

forms.py

```py
class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Application

        fields = ['programs', ...
                   ]


        labels = {
            'programs': 'Please select the programs you know of', ...
        }

        help_texts = {
            'programs': 'Leave blank if there are no programs at your school'
        }

        widgets = {
            'programs': CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        }
```

views.py

```py
class ApplicationView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    form_class = ApplicationForm
    success_url = 'success'
    template_name = 'apply.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.applicant = self.request.user
        g = Group.objects.get(name='PendingApplicants')
        g.user_set.add(self.request.user)
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: `self.request.user.mainschool` 

From your models, mainschool can be null and blank. Are you sure that it's actually set for your logged in user?

As an aside, you can (should) take out the 'tbl' part of your model names.

Comment: @Shane Thank you for responding. Yes, it is set for the user I'm testing with. Where exactly would I put the mainschool request? Does it go in the form_valid method of my view or in the save method of my form? I'm still pretty new to this and am having trouble figuring out where to put it.

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by the mainschool request. If you have a user in request.user, and that user has a mainschool set for them, then self.request.user.mainschool would access it.

Have you debugged in your form_valid method and checked to confirm that it is indeed set for your user?

Comment: I'm just not sure where to actually put the mainschool request. I can print it to the console, so I know I can access it. I don't know where or how I actually set the school_id in the ManytoMany save because I always get "null value in column 'school_id' violates not-null constraint" when I submit the form. I'm sure the profile I'm using has a school set. I feel like I'm missing something basic here.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles on this, I found the problem.

This needs to be in the class-based view:

```py
    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(ApplicationView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs.update({'user': self.request.user})
        return kwargs
```

and this needs to be in the model form to access the user:

```py
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

So this can be used to populate the associative table:

```py
        def save_m2m():
            old_save_m2m
            instance.programs.clear()
            for program in self.cleaned_data['programs']:
                tblProgramSchool.objects.create(application_id=app.id, school_id=self.user.mainschool.id, program_id=program.id)
```